# New default property on Interface not showing on class that implements interface

Tags: interface, c#-8.0

.NET, Winforms, C# 8

I am trying to define an interface that has read only properties that default to false. The plan is to only override properties that implement the interface on the ones that need a value of true:

Interface:

```
public interface IMenuActionInterface
{
    public bool CanConnect => false;
    public bool CanDisconnect => false;
}
```

Implementing class:

```
public class Connect : IMenuActionInterface
{
    public bool CanConnect => true;
}
```

When I do this I am expecting the variable test to have two properties - CanConnect (value true) and CanDisconnect (value false). The variable only has a single property "CanConnect".

```
IMenuActionInterface test = new Connect();
```

Why? Is what I want to do possible?

**EDIT**
As @DavidG points out below the variable test DOES have both properties. When I hover Visual Studio 2022 does not display the value. Bug?
[image]

Comment: `test` here absolutely does have both of those properties available. If you had made `test` to be of type `Connect` then it would only have `CanConnect`

Comment: For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EkcBRi

Comment: I experienced this phenomenon just now as well, where the default value on the interface property did not show up in the debugger. The value *is* there, just not being shown when using the debugger in Visual Studio (Community Edition). The interface property has to be explicitely set on the implementing type for it to show up in the debugger. Bug or working as intended?