# Interface default property value not being overwritten in .NET6 Winforms app, works in .NET6 console app

Tags: interface, .net-5, c#-9.0

Using .NET 5 and C# 9.

I am trying to reduce code written to eliminate mistakes down the road. This question may be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73417867/new-default-property-on-interface-not-showing-on-class-that-implements-interface).

I have a Interface defined and I want to have the boolean values default to false:

```
public interface IMenuActionInterface
{
    public bool CanConnect => false;
    public bool CanDisconnect => false;
    public bool CanHome => false;
    public bool CanPoll => false;
    public bool CanRunAutomatically => false;
    public bool CanRunManually => false;
    public bool CanPurge => false;

}
```

Then in each Interface implementation I want to just define the properties that are true:

```
internal class NotConnected : IMenuActionInterface
{
    public bool CanConnect => true;
}
```

I have a variable defined as IMenuActionInterface and assign that variable various implementations of IMenuActionInterface:

```
    private IMenuActionInterface _robotState;

    _robotState = robot.SetOptions(Trigger.Connect)


    //Code for SetOptions:
    public IMenuActionInterface SetOptions(Trigger trigger)
    {
        switch (trigger)
        {
            case Trigger.Connect:
                return new Connected();
            case Trigger.Disconnect:
                return new NotConnected();
            case Trigger.Home:
                return new Homed();
            case Trigger.StartRunning:
                return new Running();
            case Trigger.StopRunning:
                return new Homed();
            case Trigger.StartPurging:
                return new Purging();
            case Trigger.StopPurging:
                return new Homed();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(trigger), trigger, null);
        }
    }
```

In the case where I return a new NotConnected() instance of _robotState.CanConnect returns false. The debugger seems to display both the default value AND the overridden class value.

What is happening here?

I want to define all default properties in my interface and then just define properties in the implementation of the interface that need to have a different value - how?

**EDIT** The code actually returns the default false.

[image]

**Edit 2**

NotConnected class looks like this:

```
internal class NotConnected : IMenuActionInterface
{
    public bool CanConnect => true;
}
```

Homed class looks like this:

```
internal class Homed : IMenuActionInterface
{
    internal bool CanDisconnect => true;
    internal bool CanHome => true;
    internal bool CanPoll => true;
}
```

If I assign 'test = new Homed()' the value of test.CanDisconnect should return true. It does not. The output of my simplified code:

```
    IMenuActionInterface test = new NotConnected();
    Debug.WriteLine(test.CanDisconnect);
    test = new Homed();
    Debug.WriteLine(test.CanDisconnect);
```

is:

```
False 
False
```

Adding even more data to this I edited a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S8hzve) to reflect my issue and it worked as expected (False, True). I also created a .NET6 console app in visual studio and it works fine as well          (False, True). I then created a winforms app with .net6 and this pattern does not work. I get:

```
False
False
```

rather then the expected:

```
False
True
```

There is definitely different behaviour between .NET6 Console app and .NET6 winform app.

Comment: Forget the debugger, what does the code actually do?

Comment: The code actually returns the default false of the Interface rather then the true defined in the class.

Comment: So a NotConnected returns false for CanConnect? That is not what I see. Like I commented on your previous question that you ignored. Here, again, is proof https://dotnetfiddle.net/fEioER

Comment: Correct. If I instantiate a new Connected() (or any other implementation of the Interface) they still return false on the properties that are set to true. Yes, I did see your comment (thanks for that) I did not ignore it. I looked at it and was confused because the dotfiddle example worked. I have been working with my code and trying to determine the difference. I probably should have continued the last post.

Comment: Clarifying. I super simplified the code (I'll edit my post above) and it is NOT working in my version but does work in dotnetfiddle. I upgraded my app from .net5 to .net6 since that is one difference between my app and dotnetfiddle. My app is still outputting false rather then true. My app is outputting the default interface value for the property rather then the value set in the class implementing the interface.

Comment: .NET6 doesn't magically work differently in WinForms context. If you cannot show the issue here with plain C# code or in a dotnetfiddle, then your question doesn't make sense, and the problem is probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I hear you but when I create two different BRAND NEW apps with minimum reproducible code in VS 2022 they are behaving differently. Both are .NET6. The console app gets the expected result. To reproduce:

Should not work:
1) Create a new .net6 WinForm app.
2) Create a new button
3) Use this code. - https://dotnetfiddle.net/L8AY0W

Should work:
1) Create a new .NET6 console app
2) Use this code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e8SS3v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue....

I looked very carefully at my code and found that the keyword has to be public on the properties in both the Interface and the class that implements the interface.

[image]

If both are set to public then all is good:
[image]

In fact it seems the compiler is very particular with how the property is defined. These both work:

```
interface IMenuActionInterface
{
    bool CanConnect => false;
    bool CanDisconnect => false;
}

public class Testing : IMenuActionInterface
{
}

public class DoubleTesting : IMenuActionInterface
{
    public bool CanDisconnect => true;
}
```

-and-

```
interface IMenuActionInterface
{
    bool CanConnect => false;
    public bool CanDisconnect => false;
}

public class Testing : IMenuActionInterface
{
}

public class DoubleTesting : IMenuActionInterface
{
    public bool CanDisconnect => true;
}
```

It seems that if I use any other combination of modifier then it does not like it.